# Finding Top Level Tags With BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some BeautifulSoup I'm looking at. In this case, my tree looks like this:

```
soup = "<table class="myTable"><tr>...</tr></table>"
```

When I call the following:

```
soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'myTable'})
```

I don't have anything returned, when I would expect that top level tag to be returned. But if the tag I'm searching for isn't in the top level, like the following:

```
soup = "<body><table class="myTable"><tr>...</tr></table></body>"
```

Then I do find the table. I assume I'm missing something obvious. If I'm not, is there a way to have find everything including the top level tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem. I think finding the top-level tags should work:

```
In [92]: import BeautifulSoup
In [94]: soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup('<table class="myTable"><tr>...</tr></table>')

In [95]: soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'myTable'})
Out[95]: [<table class="myTable"><tr>...</tr></table>]
```

Comment: Could it be because I'm getting x from somewhere else? I have a list from a previous findAll that I'm iterating through. Each item from that list is what I'm using this particular findAll on.

Comment: Perhaps use `print(tag.prettify())` (or a debugger) to check that the contents of the tags are what you think they are.

Comment: Never figured out why it's doing that. Just hacked around it. Ah well, thanks for the help.